# Install Docker and Docker Compose on the Docker image

Tags: docker-compose, asp.net-web-api2, amazon-ecs, aws-codebuild

I am working on Containerized CI/CD. I have a web API project developed in .NET Framework 4.6.2. This application enabled docker support.

**Expected Working Scenario:**

I have to configure CI which needs to build the application as a docker image and push to ECR repository.
I have to deploy the same to ECS as well. As a final, I have to run my SQL (RDS) also as a docker and deploy as part of this.

Currently, I need to build and push the docker image to ECR.

**Current Progress:**

In order to build my application, I have created a custom docker as the build server. Please find my current docker file used to build the docker image;

```
    # escape=`

FROM microsoft/dotnet-framework:4.7.2-runtime

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]
#Install NuGet CLI
ENV NUGET_VERSION 4.4.1
RUN New-Item -Type Directory $Env:ProgramFiles\NuGet; `
    Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/v$Env:NUGET_VERSION/nuget.exe -OutFile $Env:ProgramFiles\NuGet\nuget.exe

#Install AWS CLI
RUN Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/AWSCLI64PY3.msi -OutFile AWSCLI64PY3.msi; `
    Start-Process "msiexec.exe"  -ArgumentList '/i', 'AWSCLI64PY3.msi', '/qn', '/norestart' -Wait -NoNewWindow; `
    Remove-Item -Force AWSCLI64PY3.msi; `


# Install VS Test Agent
    Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/12210068/8a386d27295953ee79281fd1f1832e2d/vs_TestAgent.exe -OutFile vs_TestAgent.exe; `
    Start-Process vs_TestAgent.exe -ArgumentList '--quiet', '--norestart', '--nocache' -NoNewWindow -Wait; `
    Remove-Item -Force vs_TestAgent.exe; ` 

# Install VS Build Tools
    Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/12210059/e64d79b40219aea618ce2fe10ebd5f0d/vs_BuildTools.exe -OutFile vs_BuildTools.exe; `
    # Installer won't detect DOTNET_SKIP_FIRST_TIME_EXPERIENCE if ENV is used, must use setx /M
    setx /M DOTNET_SKIP_FIRST_TIME_EXPERIENCE 1; `
    Start-Process vs_BuildTools.exe -ArgumentList '--add', 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.MSBuildTools', '--add', 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCoreBuildTools', '--add', 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.WebBuildTools;includeRecommended', '--quiet', '--norestart', '--nocache' -NoNewWindow -Wait; `
    Remove-Item -Force vs_buildtools.exe; `
    Remove-Item -Force -Recurse \"${Env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\"; `
    Remove-Item -Force -Recurse ${Env:TEMP}\*; `
    Remove-Item -Force -Recurse \"${Env:ProgramData}\Package Cache\"

# Set PATH in one layer to keep image size down.
RUN setx /M PATH $(${Env:PATH} `
    + \";${Env:ProgramFiles}\NuGet\" `
    + \";${Env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\TestAgent\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\" `
    + \";${Env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\")

# Install Targeting Packs
RUN @('4.0', '4.5.2', '4.6.2', '4.7.2') `
    | %{ `
        Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing https://dotnetbinaries.blob.core.windows.net/referenceassemblies/v${_}.zip -OutFile referenceassemblies.zip; `
        Expand-Archive -Force referenceassemblies.zip -DestinationPath \"${Env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\"; `
        Remove-Item -Force referenceassemblies.zip; `
    }
```

Here I have installed my prerequisites as below;

- NuGet
- AWS CLI
- List item
- VS Test Agent
- VS Build Tools

**Issue / Question:**

As the application enabled docker-compose, I can use MSBuild command to build the docker image as specified below;

```
msbuild "%~dp0SampleDevOps.sln" /p:TargetFrameworkVersion=v4.6.2 /p:Configuration=Release /p:PackageAsSingleFile=false /p:OutDir=%~dp0\artifacts\ docker-compose.dcproj
```

This commands worked successfully in my local machine (Windows 10). But when I run code build, I got error like below;

> ```
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.Docker.Sdk\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets(195,5):
> ```
>
> error : MSB0001: Internal MSBuild Error: SampleDevOps.sln unexpectedly
>   not a rooted path
>   [C:\codebuild\tmp\output\src096397699\src\github.com\xxxx\test1\docker-compose.dcproj]

Here my thought was I need to install docker and docker-compose also in my build server.

***Is my understanding, right? Am I going the correct direction?
If yes, please help me to do that from the docker file I poster earlier.
I also confused that, there is not have built-in docker which already contains this AWS CLI and dockers?***

Comment: CodeBuild runs all builds on Docker containers. Building Docker images in a Windows Docker container (Docker-in-Docker) is not yet supported.

Comment: Thanks. Yea i also read about this. So any alternatives? I need to deploy to ECS without manual work (All will be in the AWS pipeline.   Any suggestions? Maybe docker build using a separate server like Jenkins or anything like that and use as code build type